# PHP - how match 2 sets of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am building a JSON file using php, and I want to match the IDs of $Array2 with Array1, and display the matched value of the IDs of array1. How can I do that? Please see the code below:

```
$array1 = array(
    '1' => 'a', 
    '2' => 'b',
    '3' => 'c',
    '4' => 'd'
);
$string = "1,3|2,3|1,4";
$array2 = explode('|', $string);

$foo = '';

foreach ($array2 as $item) {
    $foo .= '{' . $item . '},';
}

echo $foo;
```

the result shows - `{1,3},{2,3},{1,4},` but
I want the result to be
`{a,c},{b,c},{a,d}`

Thanks alot.

Comment: what's inside `$array2` ?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with `$array1`. Am I missing something?

Comment: $string 1,3|2,3|1,4
$array2 = explode('|', $string);

Comment: @Mike please share code that is easy to copy and paste. Your original question and comments were not valid PHP. Can you give us var_dumps of array1, array2, and your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is it:

```
foreach ($array2 as $items) {
    $values = implode(',', array_map(function($i) use ($array1) {
        return $array1[$i];
    }, explode(',', $items)));
    $foo .= "{" . $values. "},";
}
```

The function in `array_map` translates the numbers in `$array2` to the corresponding values from `$array1`.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/o5QyuA)

Comment: Thanks Barmar, now I know how to match using the array_map you specified above, but how about if I want to match the ID and the name inside the object? like this - { 'ID'=>'1','Name'=>'A'}? so output the match of ID and output the name in the same object.

Comment: That has to be done using a loop to search for the ID. I suggest that if you have an array like that, you first create a new associative array like `$array1` from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function answer($string, $ids) {
    $pairs = explode('|', $string);

    return implode(',', array_map(function($pair) use ($ids) {

        // Get the first and second ID from the pair.
        list($x, $y) = explode(',', $pair);

        // Fetch from the other array and join them.
        return sprintf('{%s,%s}', $ids[$x], $ids[$y]);

    }, $pairs));
}

echo answer("1,3|2,3|1,4", array(
    '1' => 'a', 
    '2' => 'b',
    '3' => 'c',
    '4' => 'd'
));

// {a,c},{b,c},{a,d}
```

[Run this snippet](https://3v4l.org/mCnuU)

Comment: he wants to intersect the values in `$array2` with the keys in `$array1`, and get the corresponding values from `$array1`.