# PHP - how to search ID and display its value in a object

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have an array of object like this

```
$json = json_decode($featureJson);

//which returns below
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 1
            [productName] => Toyo
            [assessments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => Yes
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [answer] => Yes
                        )

                    ...

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 2
            [productName] => Maze
            [assessments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => Yes
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [answer] => Yes
                        )

                    ...

                )

        )

)
```

and I have another array that needs to match the ID of $json(Array of Objects) and return its productName.

```
$string = "1,2|2,1";
$IdArray = explode('|', $string);

$foo = '';
foreach ($IdArray as $item) {
    $foo .= '{' . $item . '},';
}
echo $foo;
```

`$foo` return `{1,2},{2,1}` and I match $json so will display - `{Toyo,Maze},{Maze,Toyo}`, how can I do that? I have some hint using [array_map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330340/php-how-match-2-sets-of-arrays?noredirect=1#comment58369030_35330340)

but still got no idea to match in objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you separate an array for the names first.

```
<?php 

    $featureJson = '[{"productID":1,"productName":"Toyo","assessments":[{"answer":"Yes"},{"answer":"No"}]},{"productID":2,"productName":"Maze","assessments":[{"answer":"Yes"},{"answer":"Yes"}]}]';

    $json = json_decode($featureJson);

    // Make an array of names
    $names = []; 
    foreach($json as $products){
            $names[$products->productID] = $products->productName;   
    };


    $string = "1,2|2,1";

    $IdArray = explode('|', $string); 
    $foo = []; 
    foreach ($IdArray as $ids) {
        $ids = explode(',',$ids);
        $fooItem = [];
        foreach($ids as $id){
            $fooItem[] = $names[$id];
        }

        $foo[]= '{' . implode(',',$fooItem) . '}'; } 
        echo implode(',',$foo);
```

Result:

```
{Toyo,Maze},{Maze,Toyo}
```

Check [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6074e05afb1eb0b8dc854f53a290fcaa7d14a903)